Manga where the MC is from a sci-fi basically futuristic world and is stuck on a fantasy planet
Basically in the first few chapters the MC is on a spaceship and is in the military. His spaceship gets attacked and ends up near a planet.
The ship is too badly damaged and so he is sent to the planet by a female personnel in a escape pod while the ship crashes somewhere else, I think but the female survived.
MC lands and eventually meets a female woman that is being attacked, MC saves her with a gun or something but the woman sustains major injuries.
Her left arm is cut off and one of her legs too, MC uses nano or micro bots to slowly heal her over the weeks while also learning the worlds language and magic with the help of an ai assistant.
Also later in the manga the MC realizes that the world is too underdeveloped and decides to take over the world or continent to hasten their growth to fight off aliens monsters.
I read this manga a few months ago and this is mostly all I can remember.

This is "The Galactic Navy Officer Becomes an Adventurer".

Sci-fi spaceship gets attacked by Bugs.
Only survivor (Captain Alan Corinth) crash lands on fantasy planet
he rescues princess attacked by bandits. He uses assault rifle and nanites in his body
Turns out that the woman that sent him down is actually AI that governs the ship itself.
later AI lady sends two clones looking like her down
Our protagonist decides to screw StarTrek's Prime Directive and build up the planet he landed on so that they can fight (defensively ofc ;-) ) in the war that he participated in.

